# What do I need to do to develop a program that finds the prime factors in a number?

Tags: c++

In this program, I needed to prompt the user for a number in which the program will find the prime factors for the number. Here's what I have so far:

```
int n;
cin >> n;

for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    bool iprime = true;
    if (n % i == 0) iprime = false; {

    }
}
```

This is all to detect if a number is prime but I have no idea what to do. My professor only taught us about bool, if/then, while, for, and how to use complete some algorithms and expressions but that's it so I need to keep the code as basic as possible to get points. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would use the bool:

```
int p;
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> p;

bool prime = true;
for(int i = 2; i < p; ++i)
{
    if(p % i == 0){
        prime = false;
    }
}
if(!prime) cout << "not"<< endl;
else cout << "prime" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this , u can use long long int for big numbers :)

```
int n=0;

cout << "Pick a Number: ";
cin >> n;

// If it's divisible to 2 then 2 is a prime factor of n and so on....
while(n%2==0)
{
    cout << "2 ";
    n=n/2;
}

    while(n%3==0)
{
    cout << "3 ";
    n=n/3;
}

    while(n%5==0)
{
    cout << "5 ";
    n=n/5;
}

    while(n%7==0)
{
    cout << "7 ";
    n=n/7;
}

// If n is not divisible to 2-7...
if(n>7)
{
    cout << n;
}

return 0;
```

}